# concatenating NSString and Int in Apple Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have used arc4random_uniform() to get the random values from given String or Int. Now I want to join those to values.

```
var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(9999) + 1000 // returns random number between 1000 and 9999 e.g. - 7501
let alphabet_array = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(alphabet_array.count)))
let random_alphabet = alphabet_array[randomIndex] // returns random alphabet e.g. - E
```

What I want is to display 7501 and E together like 7501E

```
var str="\(randomNumber)\(random_alphabet)" // error
```

I am getting below error :

```
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

Please help how can I display this together.

Comment: It works fine for me. Try restart Xcode and try again.

Comment: You're actually going to get numbers between 1000 and 10999 that way...

Comment: Assuming that your code is verbatim, you are missing an "=" on the second line

'let alphabet_array["A"'

otherwise it works as @Nate Cook says

Comment: Restarted xcode, same error

Comment: Is there any other way to display those values together???

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with the right punctuation:

```
var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(999) + 1000 
// returns random number between 1000 and 9999 e.g. - 7501 NOTE 999 not 9999

let alphabet_array = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"] 
// Note missing "=" in OP

let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(alphabet_array.count)))

let random_alphabet = alphabet_array[randomIndex] // returns random alphabet e.g. - E

var str = "\(randomNumber)\(random_alphabet)" // e.g. 1197A
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using string interpolation, you could also convert the random number to a string and just add them together:

```
let str = randomNumber.description + random_alphabet
```